# Circular dependency within generic Swift classes

Tags: swift, generics

I have generic `Parent` and `Child` classes that should both be able to reference each other:

```
class Parent<MyChild: Child<Parent<MyChild>>> {
    var children = [MyChild]()
}

class Child<MyParent: Parent<Child<MyParent>>> {
    var parent: MyParent?
}
```

I want to be able to create subclasses of `Parent` and `Child` that have a reference to each other. The generics should allow each class to use methods of the other custom class as well as those inherited by the base `Parent` and `Child` classes, which may refer to the custom generics. **EDIT**: I need not only to reference methods, but instance variables as well.

This may be comparable to an array (the parent) having a reference to the children and each child having a reference to the array it belongs to. The array would be modelled with a generic `Child` type, and the child should then be modelled with a generic `Parent` type.

This code produces the compiler error `Generic class 'Parent' references itself`. I think this is possible in Java. Is there a way of expressing such a generic relationship in Swift?

Comment: This is such a strange generics definition, maybe you should explain what you want to accomplish instead? And while it is possible to use generic types that themselves are generic it is hard to understand what you will accomplish with this kind of circular references.

Comment: I want to be able to create subclasses of `Parent` and `Child` that have a reference to each other. The generics should allow each class to use methods of the other custom class as well as those inherited by the base `Parent` and `Child` classes, which may refer to the custom generics. I've edited the question to make it clearer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use protocols to define the relationship between these types and the dependencies between them (with an [associated type with generic where clause](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Generics.html#ID557)):

```swift
protocol Parent: AnyObject {
    associatedtype C: Child where C.P == Self
    var children: [C] { get set }
}

protocol Child: AnyObject {
    associatedtype P: Parent where P.C == Self
    var parent: P? { get }
}
```

(As an aside, I made these `AnyObject` because this doubly-linked pattern requires that you are dealing with reference types. Also, I made `parent` property optional because it will need to be `weak` to avoid strong reference cycles.)

Then the actual parent and child classes can use these protocols:

```swift
class Teacher: Parent {
    var name: String
    var socialSecurityNumber: String
    var children: [Student] = []
}

class Student: Child {
    var name: String
    var admissionDate: Date
    weak var parent: Teacher?

    ...
}
```

Again, note that `parent` is a `weak` property to avoid strong reference cycle.

---

Note, when using protocols, rather than having abstract (i.e., pure virtual) `Child` and `Parent` classes, we have protocol, and our concrete classes would conform to those protocol. And if we wanted to define methods that all of these conforming classes would share, we would define default implementations in a [protocol extension](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Protocols.html#ID521). See WWDC 2015 video on [Protocol Oriented Programming](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015/408/).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, it has helped me understand how Swift protocols can be used much better. I will probably sound like a beginner now, but what I implicitly meant with `The generics should allow each class to use methods of the other custom class as well as those inherited by the base Parent and Child classes` is that I also need to have instance variables to hold some state, not only methods. I'm afraid your answer doesn't apply anymore now ... At least I wouldn't know how to subclass `Parent` and `Child` while injecting those subtypes into the parent class definitions.

Comment: There's nothing in this POP pattern that prevents your conforming classes from having their own properties. I've changed my above example with a practical example where a teacher has multiple students and each student has a single teacher. My broader point is that in POP, the protocols render this idea of abstract parent and child classes obsolete.

Comment: What I mean is that when I have stored properties that are needed inside some of the methods that should be shared across all conforming classes, there is no way of doing this with protocols as far as I know. Unless I declare the names of those properties as requirements to the protocol and add them to each conforming class ... which is something that I would like to avoid, because there can be many of them and adding or removing one would require me to change all conforming classes, while the stored properties themselves needn't necessarily be accessible outside of the superclass/protocol.